# Application stops responding when WritableBitmap.BackBuffer update in non UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I need to update the pixels of the image asynchronously. I have a problem with a solution that was suggested in this topic - [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868929/how-to-edit-a-writablebitmap-backbuffer-in-non-ui-thread).  So, the following code called from non UI thread. The application stops responding during the execution of this code:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
_bitmap.Lock();
pBackBuffer =_bitmap.BackBuffer;
});

unsafe
{
    Marshal.Copy(_displayPixels, 0, pBackBuffer, _displayPixels.Length);   
} 

Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
_bitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, DepthWidth, DepthHeight));
_bitmap.Unlock();
});
```

What am I do wrong?

Comment: As a result I using `_bitmap.WritePixels` in UI thread without `Lock\Unlock` and data manipultaion in another thread. It's work!

Answer (score 2):

Stop cargo culting. The `unsafe` block is completely useless, remove it.

That said, `_bitmap.Lock()` and `_bitmap.Unlock()` are *far* from cheap. Did you profile the application? I'm pretty sure most of the time is spent in the `Invoke` calls, which *do* run on the UI thread.

Comment: thanks for the advice.Profiler says that `PresentationFramework.dll` have 42% exclusive samples, but not from `_bitmap.Lock()`. It is not hot line. But if it's true. What is an alternative not to use `Lock`?

Comment: @CyberDreamer Reading profiler results in code like this is tricky - it's basically telling you that 42% of the work is in those `Invoke` calls (excluding the actual time spent inside the delegates, possibly - it's hard to tell). And in a way, there is no alternative - you're copying the full bitmap as a single operation; there's no place to shave off execution time. The truth is, I don't see why you're touching the backbuffer at all - why not just swap the bitmap for another bitmap when you already have it ready?

Comment: I thought about it and did the following. Create image in one non UI thread  and updated in other non UI thread through the `Dispatcher`. But i had `InvalidOperationException - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it`  on `_bitmap.Unlock()`. How it's passible?

Comment: @CyberDreamer You can only use it on the thread where it was created. Maybe you don't want to use `WriteableBitmap` at all?

Comment: Wow, even if I don't use UI thread and call `Lock/Unlock` through Dispatcher is not going to work? Where can I read about such details? What alternative for `WritableBitmap`?

Comment: I need to update Bitmap 30 times per second. Every time allocate memory for this is not cool. So how can I get memory allocate only once and multiple use in another thread?

Comment: @CyberDreamer Try this - https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ it should allow you to blit, which should be enough for you. Or just use `WritePixels`, it might be faster than your approach. It's hard to tell.

Comment: Thank you for your many answers. But... Now i have a new trouble or variant of original problem. I use `writePixels` without Lock\Unlock and application don't stops responding. But i don't see change of image on the screen. I even use a InvalidationVisual in WPF controls as analog Refresh in WinForms.

Comment: @CyberDreamer Are you sure that you're actually writing pixels that are different?

Comment: Yes. Even if i do only a single thread, the version with `Lock\Marshal.Copy\ Unlock` works well, but with `WritePixels` gives a static white screen.

Comment: Oh, it's my mistake. You will right. As a result I using `WritePixels` in UI thread, but data manipultaion in another thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead of `Dispatcher.Invoke` to run it asynchronously.

Comment: That's a terrible idea. This needs to run synchronously to work at all, and even if it didn't, that would still block the GUI thread for the duration of the `BeginInvoke`. The problem isn't blocking the non-GUI thread - it's the GUI thread that's trouble.